# In rails.. since everything passed is by reference... how does one set the "value" for return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reference, variable-assignment

In rails everything is an object... (with a few small exceptions)

If I have a variable that I want adjusted inside a function, how do I set the value.

```
###untested sudo code.### 
def test
   processed = 123
   worked = false
   process_a_pile_more_records(processed , worked) 
end
def process_a_pile_more_records(iProcessed, iWorked)
  (0..100).each do |id|
     *iProcessed += 1  #if this is c++ that's how I'd do it.
     *iWorked = true  #again c++ accessing a record.
  end
end
```

Since everything is a pointer... it should be easy as pie to do this.. But I'm buggered if I can find a bit of code that tells me how to sus this out.

Answer (score 0):

In your process_a_pile_more_records method you are instantiating the parameters to the method with the same references as defined in the test method.

However when you execute iProcessed += 1, you are actually pointing iProcessed at a new object with an incremented value instead of incrementing the original object. The same with iWorked. You are setting the iWorked to variable to point at true.

If you were to execute methods against the variables that actually changed the underlying object, then you would see the result of this in the calling method. See the following code sample where, adding an element to Array, modifies the original object or the gsub! method modifies the underling string. Note that if I had used the gsub method the changes wouldn't have been made to the underlying object as a new string would have been created.

Notice how for the second invocation of process_a_pile_more_records, the original variables in the test method are given new values based on what is returned from the process_a_pile_more_records method.

```
test "local variable manipulation" do
  processed = 123
  worked = false
  string1 = 'Hello'
  string2 = 'Goodbye'
  an_array = []

  process_a_pile_more_records(processed , worked, string1, string2, an_array)
  puts 'Output the variables'
  puts processed
  puts worked
  puts string1
  puts string2
  puts an_array.to_s
  processed, worked, string1 = process_a_pile_more_records(processed , worked, string1, string2, an_array)
  puts processed
  puts worked
  puts string1
  puts string2
  puts an_array.to_s
```

end

def process_a_pile_more_records(processed_var, worked_var, first_string, second_string, an_array)
    (0..10).each do |id|
      processed_var += 1
      worked_var = true
      first_string = first_string + id.to_s
      second_string.gsub!('oo', '00')
      an_array << id.to_s
    end
    return processed_var, worked_var, first_string
  end

This will produce the following output:

```
Testing started at 14:38 ...
Output the variables
123
false
Hello
G00dbye
["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
134
true
Hello012345678910
G00dbye
["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",     "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```